# ingress I make an https request in the logs, I see that the request goes via http

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm setting up an ingress config in AKS. Below is my ingress file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-api
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-dev
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-api
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_clear_headers Server;
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api-test.dev.test.net
      secretName: test-tls-certificate
  rules:
    - host: api-test.dev.test.net
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-api
                port: 
                  number: 80
```

But when I make a request via postman to https in the logs, I see that the request comes via http. My auth server for our apps only works over https. How can I send traffic over https only and disable http? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a yaml with values, rather than a template? It would make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: You need to enable TLS Passthrough. How this is done depends on your ingress controller. [Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough=) are the docs for the kubernetes-nginx controller

Comment: @Spirit, thanks for your answer I add nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" but looks like it`s not working for me